# How to make a counter using React Hooks which depends on two buttons start and stop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

I want to implement a counter which will start incrementing when start button is clicked and stops when we hit the stop button and at the same time counter get reinitialized with the default value 1.I am using setInterval but the behaviour is absurd.I also want this counter to go to a given value for ex 10 and then start again with 1,2 like so.

I have attached my code for reference please look into it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
function App() {
  const [increment, setIncrement] = useState(1);
  const [stop, setStopStatus] = useState(false);
  const [start, setStartStatus] = useState(false);

  if (start) {
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
      setIncrement((prev) => prev + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }

  if (stop) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  function stopStatus() {
    setStopStatus((prev) => (prev = true));
    setStartStatus((prev) => (prev = false));
    setIncrement((prev) => (prev = 0));
  }

  function startStatus() {
    setStartStatus((prev) => (prev = true));
    setStopStatus((prev) => {
      prev = false;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{ padding: "5px", margin: "5px" }}>{increment}</h1>
      <button style={{ padding: "5px", margin: "5px" }} onClick={stopStatus}>
        stop
      </button>
      <button style={{ padding: "5px", margin: "5px" }} onClick={startStatus}>
        start
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is one more code that I tried but it has a issue that it's start auto incrementing without considering start button is clicked or not it's only for the first time after it i can use start and stop to get a  hold on my counter.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
var handle;
function App() {
  const [increment, setIncrement] = useState(1);
  const [stop, setStopStatus] = useState(false);
  const [start, setStartStatus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    handle = setInterval(() => {
      setIncrement((prev) => prev + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  if (stop) {
    clearInterval(handle);
  }

  if (start) {
    handle = setInterval(() => {
      setIncrement((prev) => prev + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }

  function stopStatus() {
    setStopStatus((prev) => (prev = true));
    setStartStatus((prev) => (prev = false));
    setIncrement((prev) => (prev = 0));
  }

  function startStatus() {
    setStartStatus((prev) => (prev = true));
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{ padding: "5px", margin: "5px" }}>{increment}</h1>
      <button style={{ padding: "5px", margin: "5px" }} onClick={stopStatus}>
        stop
      </button>
      <button style={{ padding: "5px", margin: "5px" }} onClick={startStatus}>
        start
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stop` and `start` should not be stateful values - they do *one* thing - that is, alter the existing state - and are irrelevant once that's completed.

To clear the interval, put the interval ID into state so it can be set and retrieved across renders when neeeded.

Use the `%` operator to wrap around once the count reaches a certain point.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [intervalID, setIntervalID] = useState(-1);
  const startInterval = () => {
    setIntervalID(setInterval(() => {
      setCount(prev => (prev + 1) % 10);
    }, 1000));
  };
  const stopInterval = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    setIntervalID(-1);
    setCount(0);
  };
  useEffect(() => () => {
    clearTimeout(intervalID);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{ padding: "5px", margin: "5px" }}>{count}</h1>
      <button style={{ padding: "5px", margin: "5px" }} onClick={stopInterval}>
        stop
      </button>
      <button style={{ padding: "5px", margin: "5px" }} disabled={intervalID !== -1} onClick={startInterval}>
        start
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: I'd like to highlight a thing : Be sure to use the function version of the setter for your state values: `setCount(prevVal => prevVal + 1)`. I did the mistake while creating a repro

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

Your current code sets a new interval every time `App` component re-renders. This is because when start button is clicked, state is updated which leads to a re-render. As `start` is true, interval is set. When the component re-renders again, `start` is still true, so another interval is set. This is why you see the weird behavior.

**Solution:**

You need to make sure there is only one interval set at any given time and you only need to save two things in the state:

- increment
- interval id

When start button is clicked, do the following steps:

1. Check if interval id is set.
2. If it is, return from the function to avoid setting another interval.
3. If interval id is not set, set the interval by calling `setInterval` and save the id in the state.

When stop button is clicked, do the following steps:

1. Check if interval id is set.
2. If it is null, return from the function.
3. If interval id is not null, then clear the interval, set the interval id to null and set the increment to initial value, i.e. 1.

> I also want this counter to go to a given value for ex 10 and then
> start again with 1,2 like so.

To achieve this behavior, you can save the limit in a variable and then when calling `setIncrement` from the callback function of `setInterval`, check if the current state is equal to the upper limit or not. If it is, return the initial value, i.e. 1, otherwise add 1 to the state.

```js
const limit = 10;

function App() {
  const [increment, setIncrement] = React.useState(1);
  let [intervalID, setIntervalID] = React.useState(null);

  // clear the interval on unmount
  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => clearInterval(intervalID);
  }, []);
  
  function startInterval() {
    if (intervalID) return;

    let id = setInterval(() => {
      setIncrement((prev) => prev == limit ? 1 : prev + 1);
    }, 1000);

    setIntervalID(id);
  }

  function stopInterval() {
    if (!intervalID) return;
    clearInterval(intervalID);
    setIntervalID(null);
    setIncrement(1);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{ padding: "5px", margin: "5px" }}>{increment}</h1>
      <button style={{ padding: "5px", margin: "5px" }} onClick={stopInterval}>
        stop
      </button>
      <button style={{ padding: "5px", margin: "5px" }} onClick={startInterval}>
        start
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: why we are tracing interval id ?

Comment: To clear the interval when stop button is pressed or when the component unmounts.

Comment: can you please tell me while i am using this code   if (start) {
    var interval = setInterval(() => {
      setIncrement((prev) => prev + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }  why i am getting value of counter 1 ,3, 27,300 like this, why not 1,2,3, like this